# New profile appears to inherit "about me" text correctly, but edit page shows out-of-date version instead

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-accounts

A few weeks ago I edited the "about me" section on my profile on Mi Yodeya, which is the site that feeds my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/505925/monica-cellio?tab=accounts).  I've just verified that that text is up to date.

Yesterday I created an [account](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/290/monica-cellio?tab=profile) on a new site, expecting it to inherit the profile data from the network profile as it has in the past.  And, in fact, if you check the profiles, that appears to be the case:

New account:

[image: screen shot]

Network profile:

[image: screen shot]

### However...

This text is kind of specific to its original site (Mi Yodeya), so I usually end up editing that on new accounts.  This is what I found when I clicked the "edit profile" link on the new site:

[image: screen shot]

That is not the same.  That's my profile text on Mi Yodeya as of about three weeks ago.  This isn't something I just changed a few hours ago; I really don't think we can just blame caching.

Why does the text that's displayed in the new profile not match the text that's available for *editing* in that same profile?

There is, of course, an obvious workaround, but the behavior is puzzling so I'm leaving it alone for now to make investigation simpler.

Comment: Similar reports: http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/328/editing-my-profile-pulls-an-older-version, http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/bug-editing-my-bio-pulls-up-some-old-version